# How to Make Str Comparison Between htmlentities and normal string in php (with non-ascii chars)

Tags: php

When I use this code:

```
<?
$a = htmlentities(urldecode("ööö"));
$b = "ööö";

if ($a === $b){
    echo "equal.";
}
?>
```

When I runned above code, it couldn't write anything. But when I use the code below:

```
<?
$a = "ööö";
$b = "ööö";

if ($a === $b){
    echo "equal.";
}
?>
```

It writes "equal". So, I can't compare strings when they are used with htmlentities function. How can I solve this problem ?
I think the problem is about htmlentities() function. When it is used, PHP can't be able to comparison strings truely...
Thanks.

Comment: i checked both codes in fiddle, first code won't echo but 2nd code echo `equal.` so what exactly the problem is, with limited information you provided its hard to understand it.

Comment: @shehary When I use htmlentities function with $a variable, === operator can't understand is equal or not. Could you understand ?

Comment: if the output is not showing `equal` it clearly means its `not equal` you can check it like this `if ($a === $b){
    echo "equal.";
} else {echo "not equal."; }`

Comment: @shehary Yes, I know. But I want to say that: I must use htmlentities function for security while using $_GET or $_POST method. But, when I use htmlentities function with $a variable, the php script can't understand that strings are equal or not. I want to convert $a variable for === operator can understand that strings are equal or not.

Comment: @shehary Sorry. The last sentence is hard to understand. I'm correcting it:I want to convert $a variable to/into a form which operator of === will be able to understand those strings are equal or not.

Comment: i understand i checked both `$a` and `$b` and echo them, checked values, both have `ööö` but then `not equal`, interesting.

Comment: did you try like this `$a = htmlspecialchars(urldecode("ööö"));`

Comment: @shehary Thank you very much. I tried htmlspecialchars function and It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `htmlspecialchars`

```
<?php
    $a = htmlspecialchars(urldecode("ööö"));
    $b = "ööö";

    if ($a === $b){
            echo "equal.";
        } else {
            echo "not equal.";
    }
?>
```